# how to validate PKCS7 signed message signed with a self-signed cert via OpenSSL CLI

Tags: openssl, pkcs7

`openssl cms -in demo.p7m -inform DER -verify` verifies the signature on a CMS / PKCS7 encoded message but if the cert that did the signing is self-signed I get a "self signed certificate" error. ie. it doesn't seem to actually verify the CMS / PKCS7 signed message.

Any idea how I can verify a CMS / PKCS7 signed message that was signed by a self-signed cert?

Answer (score 1):

<s>#Try "-signer"
Add the "-signer" parameter.</s>

Like so:

```
openssl cms -in demo.p7m -inform DER -verify -signer MYSIGNERCERTIFICATEFILE
```

EDIT: aint' working.

Comment: It's not working meh. My P7M file: http://pastebin.com/8382eEsN(base64 decode it to get actual result) The signing cert: http://pastebin.com/D4rPmyM9 I still get the "self signed certificate" error.

Comment: Try `-CAfile MYSIGNERCERTIFICATEFILE` (instead of `-verify MYSIGNERCERTIFICATEFILE`). (And: This parameter is case-sensitive. It really must be capitalised as '-CAfile'. Other capitalisations like '-cafile' will NOT work.) -- But I think your demo.p7m is actually empty.